# Selecting multiple arrays through a random generator

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm creating multiple random generators. Once the first random generator selects a particular name the second will overide the first random generator and display the second random gernerators selection.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function postmessage() {
    var firstnames = ["John", "Jacob", ];
    var firstname = firstnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstnames.length)];


  function pickAnother(John) {
      if (John != firstnames) {
    run(sndnames);
      }
  }

  pickAnother (firstnames);

  var sndnames = ["Eric", "Conroy", ];
    var sndname = sndnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * sndnames.length)];

  </script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <input type="button" value="Get Recruit" onclick="postmessage();" />
  <div id="recruit"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I managed to get an alart message from another code, but I would like to display the sndnames like the firstnames.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking - but I also spot some items that might be wrong. Inside `pickAnother` function, you're comparing two arrays with the double equals sign - that won't work as intended (it returns false always). Additionally what does `run` do? The value of sndnames in that function should be undefined (you declare it after you call the function).

Comment: Also, needs to be `John != firstname`, not `firstnames`. Also, where are you displaying these?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's been all figured out.